# Не удается запушить проект на github

Tags: git

После создания репы на git обнаружил, что вместе с файлами залил рабочий каталог .idea
Добавил каталог в игнор, удалил его онлайн на github, сделал pull и попытка сделать push приводит вот к такому сообщению: Everything up-to-date.
Что я сделал не так и как нужно правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть, что пишет `git remote show origin`.

Comment: * remote https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/HeaTDV4A
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/HeaTDV4A
  Push  URL: https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/HeaTDV4A
  HEAD branch: master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)

Comment: Так если вы удалили на github онлайн, a затем сделали pull, то у вас рабочая копия совпадает с копией на github. Что пушить-то? Сообщение "Everything up-to-date" значит что локальная ветка совпадает с remote, поэтому пушить что-то бессмысленно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вопрос решился простым коммитом и последующим пушем.